# On the monotonicity of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be two functions such that
$$f\left(x\right) \geq g\left(x\right), \text{ for every } x \in \mathbb{R}. \tag{1}$$

Then, by *monotonicity of integrals*, we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^t f\left(x\right)\,dx \geq \int_{-\infty}^t g\left(x\right)\,dx, \text{ for every } t \in \mathbb{R}. \tag{2}$$

**My question:** Is it possible to obtain a condition, weaker than $(1)$, that implies $(2)?$

Comment: Of course $(2)$ itself is weaker than $(1)$ (and implies $(2)$)

Comment: Umm I wanted to see if there's something between $(1)$ and $(2)$..

Answer (score 1):

One such condition would be: there is a countable set $C$ such that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb R\setminus C):f(x)\geqslant g(x).$$

Comment: That's surely true but it's not *much* weaker.. is there any nontrivial condition?

Comment: If I was aware of a better one, I would have posted it.